# What timezone is Heroku server using?

Tags: heroku, timezone

What timezone does Heroku's servers use? I'm trying to use node-cron and have the timezones line up, but I can't understand what timezone Heroku is using. Here's an example.

2015-11-30T09:16:45.874086+00:00

Comment: +00:00 means GMT/UTC

Comment: Well that's showing UTC, basically - the +00:00 shows that there's no offset between local time and UTC.

Comment: hmm that makes sense. Heroku log times are odd though - within ~30 minutes of issuing "heroku logs" in my terminal, the output time went from T04:00 to T09:30. Am I interpreting this wrong also?

Comment: Perhaps you had no access between 0400 and 0930? `heroku logs` will show you the contents of the logging buffer if there are any stored there.

Comment: @JohnBeynon But I issued the two "heroku logs" commands within 30 minutes of each other

Answer (score 72, accepted):

By default Heroku will return calls for current time in UTC.

You can manually set your app's time zone by [adding a TZ environment variable](https://help.heroku.com/JZKJJ4NC/how-do-i-set-the-timezone-on-my-dyno) via the config command. Keep in mind that you must use the [tz database time zone format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).  For example, if you wanted to set your default time zone to US Central time you would use the following command (I'm assuming you have/use heroku toolbelt) :

```
heroku config:add TZ="America/Chicago"
```

EDIT: As treecoder points out in the comment below; the `TZ` ENV variable can be added via the Heroku dashboard if you prefer. Open your app's dashboard and navigate to the 'settings' tab, then under 'config variables' click the 'reveal config vars' button. You will then be able to add `TZ` = `America/Chicago` (or whatever timezone you need).

NOTE: The `TZ` environment variable does not affect logs. See the second note [here](https://help.heroku.com/JZKJJ4NC/how-do-i-set-the-timezone-on-my-dyno).

Comment: The above command adds an ENV variable `TZ`. So, I think if we go and do that manually from Heroku dashboard, then we probably don't need to run this command.

Comment: @treecoder - I hadn't considered that, just checked and you're totally correct; that works. Always good to have extra options.

Comment: Can lead to huge issues with paperclip if you have used hash_secret before, as changing the TZ on Heroku invalidates the hashes - you can't reach your attachments on s3 anymore.

Answer (score 19):

Heroku is UTC by default. Open your app in heroku and go to app `setting` and click on `Reveal Config Vars` as in image
[image]

and you have to add var as in image

[image]

> TZ=Asia/kolkata

Then it will work fine for INDIA time zone. you can choose your time zone from [time-zone-list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Answer (score 13):

Heroku is UTC by default. You *can* change it by setting an env var to `TZ=America/New_York` or whatever, but I highly recommend you don't.

It's really good practice to keep *all* your server stuff (Heroku, CMS, etc.) in sync at UTC, and to *only* change this when displaying times clientside with something like Luxon.

Keeping this stuff in sync will save you a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 2):

According to this, [Heroku Help Log](https://help.heroku.com/JZKJJ4NC/how-do-i-set-the-timezone-on-my-dyno), you can change it with TZ variable. However, this never changes your log times, as they are always UTC.