# Heroku Dyno Nodejs App Date.now() giving stuck time while server time is correct

Tags: node.js, mongodb, date, heroku, mongoose

I deployed a Nodejs App on Heroku Cloud Platform.

In mongoose model,

```
createdAt: Date.now()
createdAt: new Date()
```

both function is used, on localhost it gives correct time but on server it gives a stuck/same time for several hours. (Like 2 hours before time)
Few hours it returns the same time like "Nov 17 15:36:21 " for multiple request.

I check server time from console using bash command that was correct and returning current utc time.

I know, It's little confusing.

Conclusion

Server OS time is correct, but application returning wrong and stuck timestamp.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What timezone is Heroku server using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33995194/what-timezone-is-heroku-server-using)

Comment: @lependu This is not duplicate, because server timezone is perfect. Here's issue with Returning value of Date function