# Why JavaScript Date is always 2 hours late?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, datetime

I'm using Date in JavaScript :

```
 getCurrentDateTime = () => {
    var d = new Date(),
      dformat =
        [
          d.getDate().padLeft(),
          (d.getMonth() + 1).padLeft(),
          d.getFullYear()
        ].join("/") +
        " " +
        [
          d.getHours().padLeft(),
          d.getMinutes().padLeft(),
          d.getSeconds().padLeft()
        ].join(":");

    return dformat;
  };
```

In my Mongoose Schema :

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const LoggerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  // .. Some attributes 


  InsertDate: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  InsertDateDetailed: {
    type: String
  }
});

module.exports = Logger = mongoose.model(
  "logger",
  LoggerSchema
);
```

And it's always 2 hours late :

[image]

Why ?

Comment: What timezone are you in? :) Did you specify UTC?

Comment: Can you make sure that your date isn't in UTC ?

Comment: @Icepickle : (GMT+2)

Comment: Where is it two hours late? `InsertDateDetailed` and `InsertDate` are the same...

Comment: @HereticMonkey: The time in Israel right now is 6:28 PM , both are 2 hours late

Comment: Is your server configured with a different timezone?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert UTC date time to local date time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525538/convert-utc-date-time-to-local-date-time)

Comment: Might be good information to have in the question... And I would say the values are two hours behind, but that might just be a language thing. I'm not seeing where in your code the `getCurrentTime` function is associated with the Mongoose code.

Comment: By default JavaScript Date objects are in UTC. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141762/how-to-initialize-a-javascript-date-to-a-particular-time-zone

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon: My server is `Heroku` , it runs the `NODE JS` code.You thing it might be configured without UTC ?

Comment: [They are UTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33995194/what-timezone-is-heroku-server-using), if you want your TZ check the link how to update your instance

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon: Post at as an answer , thank you very much!

Comment: To check what your system is set to, view the output of `date.toString()`, which will include the default timezone and offset that the system is set to. It will produce a string like "Tue Nov 19 2019 10:16:35 GMT+1000 (AEST)". The plain *get\** methods return "local" values, i.e. based on the system timezone and offset. The *getUTC\** methods return UTC values, i.e. they ignore the host timezone and offset settings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What timezone is Heroku server using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33995194/what-timezone-is-heroku-server-using)