# Best Practice to Define Constants and Use Them Everywhere in Controllers using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, constants, timezone-offset

I want to define a default constant `TIME_NOW` and use it in all places I need in the controllers. I know the DateTime object of `Time.now.utc - 5.hours` will give me the Eastern Standard Time, and I want to define this constant as the `TIME_NOW` somewhere in the `ApplicationController`. What would be the best practice to do this?

Comment: Eastern Time is not always UTC-5 (EST).  Sometimes it is UTC-4 (EDT) - when daylight saving time is in effect.  You cannot just subtract hours.  See "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Answer (score 5):

I would argue that time is not really constant.

Why don't you just define a method returning the current time your preferred time zone Something like this in your `ApplicationController` might work:

```
def time_now
  Time.current.in_time_zone('EST')
end
```

Comment: When I deploy to Heroku, `Time.current.in_time_zone('EST')` does not return the Eastern Standard Time. It returns the UTC-0 time. However, `Time.now.utc` on my local machine gives me the Eastern Standard Time.

Comment: Classic [X&Y question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) then. You're not going to magically fix your time problem by assigning a constant. A constant is just like a lexical variable except the scoping is different and Ruby complains if you reassign it.

Comment: @EricCheon So your question is actually "How do I set another time zone than UTC as the default time zone on Heroku?" Is that correct? Then https://stackoverflow.com/a/37886268/2483313 might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

May be something like this in `ApplicationController`

```
def time_now
  Time.now.in_time_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)')
end
```

Or more flexible

```
def time_now_in_zone(zone)
  Time.now.in_time_zone(zone)
end

def eastern_time_now
  time_now_in_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)')
end
```

And you can call this methods in all controllers beacause they are children of of `ApplicationController`

Comment: When I deploy to Heroku, Time.current.in_time_zone('EST') does not return the Eastern Standard Time. It returns the UTC-0 time.