# Why Are Heroku Logs Timestamped UTC After Setting TZ Environment Variable To Another Time Zone?

Tags: heroku, logging, timezone, environment-variables, heroku-cli

After following the procedure noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37886268/1011722) to change server time zone for a dyno the timestamp was still showing UTC using the command `heroku log --tail` or viewing logs on the application dashboard.

For example a Heroku contributor was trying to set IST via `TZ="Asia/Kolkata`, and I have done the same using `TZ=America/New_York`. However the timestamp in the log remains UTC regardless of the time zone chosen in the `TZ` environment variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented [here](https://help.heroku.com/JZKJJ4NC/how-do-i-set-the-timezone-on-my-dyno), the `TZ` environment variable will not affect logs. Heroku logs are always timestamped in UTC.